# How to sort data ASC by total count of word in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, mongodb

I'm looking for a query which returns all exact matches first followed by rows that contain one or more words of the search string ordered by word count.

If a users searches for a the word "Banana" the query should return all rows that contain only "Banana", followed by "Banana" +1 word
then "Banana" +2 words and so on.

**Example 1**:

Search "Banana":

1. Banana
2. Banana Split
3. Banana Cakes
4. Banana Cream Biscuits
5. ...

**Example 2:**

Search "Banana Cakes":

1. Banana Cakes
2. Banana
3. Cakes
4. Banana Split
5. Chocolate Cakes
6. Banana Cream Biscuits
7. ...

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: So would the second example also return `Chocolate Cakes`, because it contains `Cakes`?

Comment: @Qirel ,
yes exact match appear first.

Comment: @Dmitry ,
I haven't code, I'm currently trying from scratch

Comment: a thought: `length(string) - length(replace(string,' ','')`

Comment: This is a "requirements dump". Please do not post a question until AFTER you have tried something, researched, tried some more, researched some more, then got stuck.  Volunteers are not here to do your work for you for free, we are here for you when you cannot do something yourself.  Think of code as cars; we are mechanics not manufacturers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  I'm not sure why `php` and `node.js` tags are on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#1st Query
SELECT *,LENGTH(fname)-LENGTH(replace(fname,' ','')) as word_count FROM mytable
ORDER BY word_count ASC;

#2nd Query
SELECT A.fname, LENGTH(A.fname)-LENGTH(replace(A.fname,' ','')) as word_count FROM mytable A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT *,LENGTH(fname)-LENGTH(replace(fname,' ','')) as w_count FROM mytable WHERE fname='Banana Cakes') B
ON A.fname=B.fname
ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.fname IS NOT NULL THEN B.w_count END DESC, 
         CASE WHEN B.fname IS NOT NULL THEN LENGTH(B.fname) END DESC, 
         word_count ASC;
```

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gwZj9yMp43dhmzaETKghd/4

So the first one is simple, just need to order by length ascending and `fname` descending (since your example show `Banana Split` to return first instead of `Banana Cakes` despite both have similar length and word count. Alphabetically, 'C' comes first so `Banana Cakes` should return first).

The second query I made the condition of 'Banana Cakes' query to become a sub-query then `LEFT JOIN` it with the main table. On the `ORDER BY` I'm using `CASE` expression whereby if the result from the `LEFT JOIN` (result from the sub-query) is not NULL, ORDER using that value first and then the second order condition is similar to the first order condition in the 1st query.

**Edit:** Adding word count condition for the ordering. Note this word count function is calculating how many space(s) instead of how many word(s). Example: `0` means only a word without any space and `1` means two words with 1 space.

Comment: I want result ASC by word count not character. If i add one more fruit named "Banana a b" then it's comes on second position while it's come on last or last to second

Comment: Oh yes.. I see that.. Ok I think I know what to do. Let me update first.

Comment: Subquery? I doubt I wouldn't entertain this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean @mickmackusa . Is this an acceptable approach?

Comment: Are you able to construct an approach that doesn't query the same table twice?

Comment: Well, I had this idea of using variables etc but when I see mitkosoft's answer, I felt like I'm over-doing it on my current answer... let alone trying an audacious attempt to incorporate a bunch of variables.. sigh

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP` and exact order for that, together with words count ordering:

**Banana** string:

```
SELECT 
    fruit 
FROM 
    fruits 
WHERE 
    fruit REGEXP 'Banana' 
ORDER BY 
    (fruit = 'Banana') DESC, 
    (LENGTH(fruit) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fruit,' ',''))),
    fruit
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+
| fruit                 |
+-----------------------+
| Banana                |
| Banana Cakes          |
| Banana Cream          |
| Banana Split          |
| Banana Cream Biscuits |
+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Banana Cakes** string:

```
SELECT 
    fruit 
FROM 
    fruits 
WHERE 
    fruit REGEXP 'Banana|Cakes' 
ORDER BY 
    (fruit = 'Banana Cakes') DESC, 
    (LENGTH(fruit) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fruit,' ',''))),
    fruit
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+
| fruit                 |
+-----------------------+
| Banana Cakes          |
| Banana                |
| Cakes                 |
| Banana Cream          |
| Banana Split          |
| Chocolate Cakes       |
| Banana Cream Biscuits |
+-----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: check my comment on second answer's below